# How do I stop other players from offering to buy technologies from my company?

Tags: capitalism-2

In *Capitalism 2*, how do I stop competitors from offering to buy technologies from my company? I have the highest technology level in many products, so I am getting many offers from competitors who want to buy technology from my company. I am getting increasingly annoyed with this because I do not intend to sell technology. These offers pop up all the time, and cause the game to pause. Is there a way to permanently ignore these offers? In the game options, there is a setting to disable pop-ups for tender offers, but I don't see anything for technology offers.

[image: Competitor offering to buy technology in Capitalism 2]

Comment: The option to ignore technology offers is apparently present in Capitalism Lab but not in Capitalism 2.